# Proving Markov's property $P(T\le x+t\mid T>t)=P(T\le x)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing

I am having difficulty proving Markov's property. My proof is below, however I strongly feel that I am proving it totally wrongly. Can someone please help me prove the property? Thanks

> Prove that for an exponential distributed continuous random variable $T$ $$P(T\le s+t\mid T>t)=P(T\le s)$$

**Proof:** \begin{align}P(T\le s+t\mid T>t)=\frac{P(T\le s+t,T<t)}{P(T\le t)}=\frac{T\le s+t}{P(T\le t)} \hspace{20pt}\tag1\end{align}
We know: $P(T\le t)=1-P(T>t)=1-(1-e^{-λx})=e^{-λx},$ so from $(1)$ 
$$P(T\le s+t\mid T<t)=\ldots=\frac{e^{-λ(s+t)}}{e^{-λt}}=e^{-λs-λt+λt}=e^{-λs}$$

Comment: No, your proof seems ok to me.

Comment: Thanks @JimmyR.Just had doubts

Comment: The number of places where your proof goes astray is impressive... First, you use the wrong identity $$P(T\le s+t\mid T>t)=\frac{P(T\le s+t,T<t)}{P(T\le t)}$$ instead of $$P(T\le s+t\mid T>t)=\frac{P(T\le s+t,T>t)}{P(T>t)}$$ Second you replace $P(T\le s+t,T<t)$ by $P(T\le s+t)$, which is obviously wrong. Third you think that $P(T>t)=1-e^{-λx}$ (probably meaning $1-e^{-λt}$ instead) although this is wrong. Please revise thoroughly.

Comment: @JimmyR. "No, your proof seems ok to me." **Ouch!**

Answer (score 1):

The correct identity is $$\mathbb P(T>s+t\mid T>t)=\mathbb P(T>s),\ s,t\geqslant0. $$
This follows from the direct computation:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(T>s+t\mid T>t) &= \frac{\mathbb P\left(\{T>s+t\}\cap\{T>t\}\right)}{\mathbb P(T>t)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb P(T>s+t)}{\mathbb P(T>t)}\\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda(s+t)}}{e^{-\lambda t}}\\
&= e^{-\lambda s}\\
&= \mathbb P(T>s).
\end{align}